# Проблема смены языка сразу после оформления заявки wc+polylang

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, polylang

С wc установлен polylang (не про), также оформление заявки и корзина объединены в одну страницу, и проблема в оформлении заявки, когда ее оформляешь то в любом случае страница спасибо открывает на англ (язык по умолчанию) (подобная ссылка - /shop/my-account/checkout/order-received/375/?key=wc_order_DfVRyaBcSruLz)

Пробовал изменить ссылку фильтром woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url, но уже на этот момент движок определяет язык по умолчанию

Как реализовать перевод страницы order_received?

Оформление и корзина объединены так:

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]'); ?>

    <?php
    add_action('woocommerce_after_cart', 'natnset_after_cart', 10);
    do_action('woocommerce_after_cart'); ?>
</div>

<?php
remove_all_filters('woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals');
do_action('woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals'); ?>

<?php
/**
 * Cart collaterals hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_cross_sell_display
 * @hooked woocommerce_cart_totals - 10
 */
remove_all_filters('woocommerce_cart_collaterals');
do_action('woocommerce_cart_collaterals');
?>
```

Те в шаблон cart вставлен шорткод оформления

Comment: Отвечаю на незаданный вопрос - нужно использовать дополнения для WC. Есть 2 бесплатных.

Comment: @SeVlad, И что же это за два бесплатных плагина?

Comment: Плагины для интеграции полиланга и WC. Отвечая на следующий не заданный вопрос - они есть в репо.

Comment: @SeVlad, что за "репо"? Установил "WooCommerce Polylang Integration", но как раз с этой страницей не сработало

Comment: На SO такие вопросы - моветон. Репо - репозиторий. https://wordpress.org/plugins/

Comment: @SeVlad, как раз использовал один из них, но как видите возникла проблемка

Comment: Об этом ничего не сказано в вопросе. Как и многое другое. Например какая-такая страница "спасибо", как появилась (зачем она вообще появилась - отдельная загадка). Ну и да, есть и второй плагин.

Comment: @SeVlad, страница "order_received" идущая сразу после клика на кнопку (и обработки) оформления заказа, шаблон стандартный. Вроде бы стандартные моменты woocommerce

Comment: @SeVlad., дополнил вопрос, может вам это что-нибудь даст

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131542/discussion-between-sevlad-and-ck1e).

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы потрудитесь и зайдёте на страницу плагина https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/ , в раздел **Часто задаваемые вопросы**, пункт **Совместим ли Polylang с WooCommerce?** Вы увидите, что плагин не дружит с WooCommerce, без платного плагина. Возможно есть и бесплатные, но разработчик отвечает, что без костыля, работать с WooCommerce - не будет.

Я вижу два выхода:

1. купить премиум костыль,
2. найти премиум и посмотреть как "устроена дружба" и наколотить своих костылей.